# Consulta en Access con fechas

Tags: c#, date, datetime, ms-access

Tengo un problema al hacer una consulta en access.

verán tengo un campo Inicio_Fecha, el cual tiene un formato "Fecha Corta" y el cual es de tipo fecha. El problema que tengo es que al intentar hacer un BETWEEN no me trae ningun registro, siendo que si tendría que traerlo, inclusive intente traer cualquier registro indicándole una fecha al campo Inicio_Fecha y ni así me lo trae.
Probé las misma consulta (BETWEEN y consulta normal) en un sql y sin problema me trae los registros, pero en access no.
Investigando un poco me percate que para consultar con fechas en access, se debe utilizar previamente el simbolo # pero ni así me funcionó.
estas son mis consultas y campos, no sé si tenga algo que ver con el formato de fecha.

tabla eventos
nombre:       evento1
Inicio_Fecha: 10/10/2019 11:07:10 a. m.
Fin_Fecha:    17/10/2019 11:07:10 a. m.

query:

select * from eventos where Inicio_Fecha = #10/10/2019#;
select * from Eventos where #11/10/2019# BETWEEN Inicio_Fecha AND Fin_Fecha

He intentado cambiar el formato (dd/mm/yyyy) cno guion en lugar de digonal y de todas las formas posibles, inclusive añadiendo en el where la hora, y el query corre pero no me tare ningún registro cuando claramente el registro si existe.
Usaría mejor sql pero esta base es consumida por una aplicación en c# que accede a ese access compartido, por ello no pude ocupar sql.
¿Qué podría estar pasando? no sé si sea el formato de fecha en access o algo parecido.

Espero me puedan ayudar de favor.
Les agradezco de antemano por su apoyo.
Muchísimas gracias y excelente día.

Comment: Tiene todo que ver con el formato de la fecha. Como le estas pasando los parametros a esa query? de donde tomas los parametros? que formato tiene el campo en la base de datos? lo que vos veas por pantalla, no tiene nada que ver con el formato real de los datos, que es lo que esta comparando el query. Y access tambien usa SQL, asi que no se a que te referis cuando hablas de SQL, porque SQL es el nombre del lenguaje de consulta.

Comment: Gracias por tu retro bro!
Verás, por el momento no le estoy pasando parametros, simplemente quisiera saber el porqué ni siquiera esta pequeña consulta me corre 
select * from eventos where Inicio_Fecha = #10/10/2019#;
El tipo de datos en la base de datos es: Fecha/Hora. Y el formato está como fecha corta.
hacia referencia mas bien al motor sql server que uso, ya que ahí sin ningún problema me corre la consulta.
Sinceramente no se que pueda hacer amigo, te agradecería mucho si me pudieras ayudar.

Comment: El formato, es solamente el formato de vista, no tiene nada que ver con el formato del dato ;).. o sea, si pusiste fecha hora, esta guardando una fecha y una hora.. proba convertirlo a fecha pura y ahi si va a funcionar mejor. Tambien, fijate que los formatos sean exactamente iguales...